# Disable ActionCable broadcast for specific browser tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have a web application based on Rails v7.0.4 that typically runs in multiple browser tabs. When the user performs a certain action like logging out in one of the tabs, a confirmation dialog triggered by a flash message shall be displayed in this tab. For all other tabs, a session-wide ActionCable broadcast is used to redirect them to the login page.

Due to the fact that the broadcast is also received by the tab that is supposed to show the confirmation, this tab is also redirected to the login page and does not show the confirmation dialog. I cannot add any special parameters to this broadcast as it is triggered by an external authentication server.

My idea to solve this problem was to disable the ActionCable connection or channel for this particular tab when processing the action ideally in the backend. I found two potential options:

**1. Using [stop_stream_from](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Streams.html#method-i-stop_stream_from)/[stop_stream_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Streams.html#method-i-stream_for)**

When pressing the button in the frontend, a message is sent from this tab to the backend which then triggers `stop_stream_from`.

```
// app/javascript/controllers/session_controller.js
unsubscribe_stream() {
    let sessionChannel = consumer.subscriptions.subscriptions.find( channel => channel.identifier.includes("SessionChannel") );
    if(sessionChannel) {
        sessionChannel.send({
            action: "unsubscribe_stream"
        });
    }
}
```

```
# app/channels/session_channel.rb
def subscribed
        @session_identifier = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(connection.session_parameters["session_identifier"])
        @stream_identifier = "session_channel_#{@session_identifier}"
        stream_from(@stream_identifier)
end

def receive(data) 
    case data["action"]
    when "unsubscribe_stream"
        stop_stream_from(@stream_identifier)
    end 
end
```

Unfortunately, this seems to stop the stream for all tabs. At least, the other tabs do not receive the broadcast anymore and are not redirected to the login page.

**2. Disconnecting the associated [remote connection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/RemoteConnections.html)**

As each tab has its own connection, it should be possible to disable this connection selectively with `disconnect` to hide the broadcast for the associated tab. I gave each connection a random identifier.

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
    class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
        identified_by(:connection_identifier)
        
        connect()
            self.connection_identifier = SecureRandom.hex(32)
        end
    end
end
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to store these random identifiers outside of the connection instance in order to use them later in my controller for disconnecting the connections. I cannot use the session as this is shared among all tabs. As far as I know, there is also no way to identify the connection that belongs to the currently executed controller action.

```
ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(connection_identifier: ???).disconnect
```

I would need a nonvolatile identifier that is readable in my controller as long as the tabe is not fully reloaded. I thought about using request identifiers, but due to Hotwire these change too often when the user interactes with the frontend.

**Update**: I just saw in the logs that I had a typo in my channel code which prevented option 1 from working. Now that I fixed it, it sort of works but in my tests the confirmation dialog is shown on some of the other tabs as well. I guess this is a timing issue.

Nevertheless, I would actually prefer a pure backend solution that does not require additional Stimulus actions or events listeners in the frontend.